# Accessing android.provider.Settings.System values from platform code

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native, android-2.3-gingerbread

Is there a way to access Settings.System (i.e. persistent values) from platform code?

The idea is to read in some specific values from the storage area for data defined in Settings.System (if one exists).

So I see it as something like:

Manager.java ->(add data)-> [Settings.System database] ->(pull out data)-> DataManager.cpp

Manager.java and DataManager.cpp run completely separate from one another and in different processes.

Maybe someone could explain how persistent values operate on a low level or point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Edit: Ok, so there is a db file under data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this.
You can find the settings database by executing the following:

```
   $ adb shell
   $ su
   # find data -name "settings.db" -print
   data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

And then use sqlite3 to read in values at a native level.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no native API, you need to use JNI.

Comment: Do you know the name of the file that includes Settings.System functions?

Comment: You don't need a file -- just use the public API described in the SDK.

Comment: Sorry about unselecting your answer. I've heavily edited my question to clarify what I want to know. Cheers.